# Vue 3 Typescript warning on Vue $emit and $event "Object is possibly 'null'"

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

How to get rid of the TS warning in Vue template?

[image]

I'm using the example provided in [Vue 3 manual](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#multiple-v-model-bindings)

```html
<input 
   type="text"
   :value="title"
   @input="$emit('update:title', $event.target.value)"
>
```

Note: This only an TS warning, this works as it should.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My solution with help of [Mic Fung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67435445/1167144). Create an handler method...

```js
import { defineEmits } from 'vue'
const emit = defineEmits(['update:value'])

const updateValue = (e: Event) => {
  emit('update:title', (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
};
```

```html
<input
  :value="value"
  type="text"
  @input="updateValue"
/>
```

My option on the root of the problem: https://github.com/vuejs/jsx-next/issues/234

Comment: If you use a bundler that allows types in template, you can use just `@input="$emit('update:title', ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)"`

Comment: thanks Papooch! A lot easier!

Comment: Now on [Vue Guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-event-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use optional chaining to handle null situation

```
$event?.target?.value 
// the two `?` do the following
// if $event is null, the output will be null
// if $event.target is null, the output will be null

// if $event.target.value is null, the output will be null
// only if $event.target.value has value, the output will contain value
```

---

**UPDATED**

If you confirm the event has target and target has value
you can use `!` to tell typescript there must be target and value in $event

```
$event!.target!.value
```

Comment: I try but then i had a new warning on ".value" - Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Comment: @sainf , updated answer, see if it is what you need

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But i can't use the " ! " operator in  vue template.

Comment: so . may be you refactor that line to put into method. or you can use a tedious checking to get rid of the type checking error `$emit('update:title', $event && $event.target && $event.target.value)`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure out how to do this with JSDoc (standard JS Typescript for VS Code) and within the inline property of @change on the component. (so without the need of an extra function), this is what eventually worked:

@change="event => (modelValue = /**@type {HTMLInputElement} */ (event.target).value)"

This way, you cast the event.target to an HTMLInputElement, which has a value property.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [typed `defineEmits`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#type-only-props-emit-declarations) you can type the `value` of the `$event.target.value` using `HTMLInputElement["value"]` and then call it [as explained by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67441785/13636612).

It will be something like this:

```html
<template>
  <input
    type="text"
    :value="title"
    @input="$emit('update:title', ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value))"
  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "update:title", value: HTMLInputElement["value"]): HTMLInputElement["value"];
}>();
</script>
```